# Perl sort array by pattern match

Tags: perl, sorting

I would like to sort this array based on the value after the comma

```
my @coords;
$coords[0] = "33.7645539, -84.3585973";
$coords[1] = "33.7683870, -84.3559850";
$coords[2] = "33.7687753, -84.3541355";

foreach my $coord (@sorted_coords) {
    print "$coord\n";
}
```

Output:

```
33.7687753, -84.3541355
33.7683870, -84.3559850
33.7645539, -84.3585973
```

I've thought about using map, grep, and capture groups as the list input for `sort`, but I haven't gotten very far:

`my @sorted_coords = sort { $a <=> $b } map {$_ =~ /, (-*\d+\.\d+)/} @unique_coords;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you could use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).  You had the right idea:

```
my @coords;
$coords[1] = "33.7683870, -84.3559850";
$coords[2] = "33.7687753, -84.3541355";
$coords[0] = "33.7645539, -84.3585973";

my @sorted_coords = map  { $_->[0] }              # 3. extract the first element
                    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }  # 2. sort on the second
                                                  #    element, descending
                    map  { [ $_, /,\s*(\S+)$/ ] } # 1. create list of array refs
                    @coords;

foreach my $coord (@sorted_coords) {
    print "$coord\n";
}
```

Edit: Adding Joshua's suggestion:

```
my @sorted_coords = map  { join ', ', @$_ }
                    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }  
                    map  { [ split /, / ] }
                    @coords;
```

It seems easier to look at and more descriptive than my original example.

Comment: Thanks for linking the algorithm! I can use this idiom for other strings, not just this use case :P

Comment: The only thing I would change is to swap out the comparatively expensive regex capture with a split instead: `map  { [ $_, (split ',')[1] ] }`

Comment: I prefer to always use // around the split RE, just to show that it is a regular expression, not just a string (e.g. split '|' does not split on pipes) (the special `split ' '` being an exception)

Comment: @ysth: It also helps to contrast `/ /` and `' '` as the *PATTERN* parameter, which behave very differently

Comment: careful when doing split/joins; split by default discards trailing fields, so your code will turn "1, 2, " into just "1, 2"; if you are going to want the original string, it is often better to just keep it around.

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to submit to the temptation to use a fancy implementation instead of something straightforward and clear. Unless the data set is huge, the speed advantage of using a transform is negligible, and comes at the cost of much reduced legibility

A standard sort block is all that's necessary here

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @coords = (
    "33.7645539, -84.3585973",
    "33.7683870, -84.3559850",
    "33.7687753, -84.3541355",
);

my @sorted_coords = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map { (split)[1] } $a, $b;
    $bb <=> $aa;
} @coords;


print "$_\n" for @sorted_coords;
```

#### output

```
33.7687753, -84.3541355
33.7683870, -84.3559850
33.7645539, -84.3585973
```

---

#### Update

If you prefer, the second field may be extracted from the input records using a regex instead. Replacing the `map` statement with something like this

```perl
my ($aa, $bb) = map /.*(\S+)/, $a, $b;
```

will work fine